# Is a Brokerage obligated to sell "In the money" Warrants prior to expiration?

Tags: warrants, discount-broker

Company Press Notice of the public  warrant's pending expiration date was not made. Nor was the broker's notice of the pending expiration received until  after the expiration date and time. Before  expiration sale price was well above that after.

Comment: You can't exercise warrants after expiration, so how would they have a price after?

Comment: "prior to expiration" is ambiguous, because **every** moment from purchase up to expiration is "prior to expiration".

Comment: @RonJohn but it is also possible to not sell prior to expiration.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's a security, a warrant is effectively a long term option.  Assuming that there are no special exchange rate provisions, then at expiration, a call warrant warrant is worthless if below the exercise price and worth its intrinsic value if in-the-money.

Your broker was remiss for not advising you about the expiration in a timely fashion.  AFAIK, they have no obligation to sell or exercise your warrant unlike options and the OCC.